# Azure devops powershell task issue

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-devops, zip, compress-archive

Could someone help me with how to zip multiple files using powershell task? I am using a windows vm ..hence couldn't use zip command.

I have multiple files which need to be zipped to a particular folder with different name.

I tried to do as below, but I'm getting an error on the second line.

Error:

```
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.


Finishing: PowerShell Script
```

pipeline:

```
Compress-Archive -Path 'FR1PHPPRDAPP1V\*' -DestinationPath 'Output\APP1V.zip'
Compress-Archive -Path 'FR1PHPPRDAPP4V\*' -DestinationPath 'Output\APP4V.zip'
Compress-Archive -Path 'FR1PHPPRDAPP5V\*' -DestinationPath 'Output\APP5V.zip
Compress-Archive -Path 'FR1PHPPRDSRE1V\*' -DestinationPath 'Output\SRE1V.zip
Compress-Archive -Path 'FR1PHPPRDAPP7V\*' -DestinationPath 'Output\APP7V.zip
```

Comment: Can you show the full error message? Looks like you cut off the first couple of lines

Comment: Please also check what powershell version you have ` $PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Comment: Hello, I have edited the error..it just got exited after the error and powershell version is 5.1

Answer (score 0):

It worked..I just had to add a semicolon in between the lines.